# number subsubsection

Tags: titlesec

I have a problem formatting my subsubsection title using `titlesec`.
From my code, I would have thought the Subsubsection title was numbered I.1.1 but I don't see any number on my resulting file:

[image: result]

I noticed that by passing `\documentclass{article}`, the problem did not occur

Do you have any idea where the problem could come from?

My code:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{picinpar}

\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}



\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{moresize}

\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}

\usepackage{pgf-spectra}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*6}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\Large \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*5}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\large \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\alph{subsubsection}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*5}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\large \bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{*3}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]{\normalsize \bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{*3}{*0.5}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}
        \mainmatter
        \chapter{Chapter1}
        \section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the numbers of `\subsection`-level headers -- and, presumably, of `\section`-level headers as well -- to include the chapter number, you need to change

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\Large \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{1em}{}
```

to

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE\bfseries}{\arabic{chapter}.\Roman{section}.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{chapter}.\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{1em}{}
```

If you want subsubsection-level headers to be numbered, you further need to run

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

as the default value of the `secnumdepth` counter is `2` in the `book` document class.